# Rails RSpec form datepicker and select failing test assertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, datepicker, assertion

I'm getting to grips with testing in rails, and I've been following [this tutorial.](https://youtu.be/AAqPc0j_2bg)

However, unlike the tutorial in my form I have a date select field. This seems to be causing a problem where the assert_select doesn't recognise it, and so the test is failing.

The code in new.html.erb_spec:

```
RSpec.describe "aquatics/new", type: :view do
  current_user = User.first_or_create!(email: 'me@mail.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')

  before(:each) do
    assign(:aquatic, Aquatic.new(
        nick_name: "nickname",
        common_name: "common name",
        scientific_name: "scientific name",
        sex: 'male',
        purchased_on: '2022-02-02',
        length: 10,
        max_lifespan: 5,
        user: current_user,
        notes: "These are the testing notes"
    ))
  end

  it "renders new aquatic form" do
    render
    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", aquatics_path, "post" do
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[nick_name]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[common_name]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[scientific_name]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[purchased_on]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[sex]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[length]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[max_lifespan]"
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[notes]"
    end
  end
end
```

The failure:

```
  1) aquatics/new renders new aquatic form
     Failure/Error: assert_select "input[name=?]", "aquatic[purchased_on]"
     
     Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected at least 1 element matching "input[name="aquatic[purchased_on]"]", found 0..
       Expected 0 to be >= 1.
     # ./spec/views/aquatics/new.html.erb_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/views/aquatics/new.html.erb_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

I assume this is something to do with it being a selection field rather than an input, because if I comment out the purchased_on test line it throws the same error for the sex field.

I've tried changing the input[name=?] to date_select[name=?] and similar actions, but no luck. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

`date_select` adds 3 select tags for `Year`, `Month`, and `Date`

You are verifying `input` tag, you should verify `select` tags.

```
date_select("aquatic", "purchased_on")
```

Above date_select will generate below html

```
<select id="aquatic_purchased_on_1i" name="aquatic[purchased_on(1i)]">
    ...
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022" selected="selected">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="aquatic_purchased_on_2i" name="aquatic[purchased_on(2i)]">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">February</option>
    ...
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="aquatic_purchased_on_3i" name="aquatic[purchased_on(3i)]">
    ...
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11" selected="selected">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    ...
</select>
```

You can verify it as below

```
assert_select "select[name=?]", "aquatic[purchased_on(1i)]"
assert_select "select[name=?]", "aquatic[purchased_on(2i)]"
assert_select "select[name=?]", "aquatic[purchased_on(3i)]"
```